# Most efficient way to find all common factors of any two numbers

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I have not been able to find any questions on Math Exchange nor Stackoverflow that answer this specific question. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343024/common-factors-greatest-common-factors-least-common-factor) is the most similar question that I have found, but the question is so poorly constructed that the answer is completely inadequate.

I have tried looking on Google to no avail. I did find [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/factors-all-tool.html), but the formula seems incredibly inefficient and therefore insufficient. For instance, if we took the number 21...

```
21 % 1 = 0
21 % 2 = 1
21 % 3 = 0
21 % 4 = 1
21 % 5 = 1
21 % 6 = 3
21 % 7 = 0
...
```

Now imagine finding the common factors of numbers much greater than 21, such as 2,252 and 4,082... The method above would not be efficient whatsoever.

What I am trying to do is figure out the most efficient way to find all of the common factors of any two numbers.

**What is the most optimal method to find the common factors of any two numbers?**

I was instructed in this [Math Exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576881/find-common-factors-of-any-two-numbers) to first find the greatest common denominator by using the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), which can be written like so:

```
const gcd = (a, z) => a ? gcd(z % a, a) : z
```

I was then instructed by Alice to do a [prime factorization](https://www.mathsisfun.com/prime-factorization.html) of both numbers, which I can in turn compare to get all of the common prime factors, from which all common non-prime factors can be derived. Notably, I am not even sure how to write this as code just yet.

**I am wondering whether or not this is any more efficient than simply using the modulus operator (`%`) to check all of the integers below the greatest common denominator one-by-one?**

Comment: The answers you already have at math.stackexchange.com look pretty good to me. Note that a key point is that *every* common divisor is a divisor of the *greatest common divisor*, which is why all those answers start by finding the gcd. Then you're reduced to the problem of simply enumerating all divisors a of a given number (in this case, the gcd of your two original numbers).

Comment: @MarkDickinson if that is actually the case, can you explain which answer **in a programming context** is more efficient than simply using the modulus operator to check all of the integers below the greatest common denominator one-by-one?!

Comment: What size numbers? Are you interested in what's most efficient in the limit as the numbers become huge? Or do you have a particular target size in mind?

Comment: @MarkDickinson numbers no larger than roughly 2,000. what i'm trying to do is create a grid (of squares), which can be scaled, on top of an element that will be no larger than the maximum height of `window.innerHeight` at any resolution (so roughly 4K max which works out to 2100-and-something pixels).

Comment: Okay, then finding the gcd is cheap, and should definitely be your first step (not least since it simplifies the problem and the resulting code). For finding the divisors efficiently, prime factorization is probably overkill for such small numbers; just test all potential divisors up to (and including) the square root of the gcd, and use the fact that if `d` is a divisor of `g` then so is `g/d` (and vice versa). I'll leave it to someone more JavaScript-friendly to write an answer with code ... Oh: and if you care about efficiency, PROFILE!

Comment: Um....  Factoring numbers is theoretically difficult.  That's why all modern encryption is at least partially based on it.  It's no surprise you get all bad answers everywhere.  If you come up with a great one, you get murdered in the first ten minutes of the movie.  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakers_(1992_film) )

Comment: @DylanB: Yeah, but the OP is dealing with numbers no bigger than 4000 ...  Factoring numbers of that size isn't terribly difficult.

Comment: Because brute force is easy at that size.  I can probably write something to build a table through brute force for every number that size that'll run in less than a minute.

Comment: @MarkDickinson hm... why up to only the square root? i can already imagine problems with that. for instance, if the two numbers we were comparing were `10` and `20`, of which the gcd is of course `10`, if we only only tested up to and including the root of `10` we would end up missing `5` as a common factor :/ also, `d` as in an integer that is a factor and `g` as in the gcd?

Comment: @DylanB lol!!!!

Comment: @Anthony: Because if `d` is a divisor of `g` that's bigger than the square root of `g`, then `g/d` is a divisor that's *smaller* than the square root of `g`. So it's enough to find all divisors not exceeding the square root, and then include both `g/d` and `d` in the final results for each divisor `d` you find. It's a cheap optimisation. In the example you give, `g` is `10`, and you'll find `2` as a divisor, which also gives you `10/2 = 5`. And yes, `g` is the gcd in this case, and `d` represents a divisor of `g`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson ok, i kind of get what you're saying. `gcd / 2` will always be bigger than the root, but will `gcd / 2` be the *only* divisor greater than the root of `gcd` or are there cases where there are multiple divisors that are greater than the root of `gcd`?

Comment: @Anthony: Yes, there are cases where there are multiple divisors of `g` larger than the square root of `g`. In fact, that's the *normal* case. Divisors of any positive integer `g` come in pairs: if `d` is a divisor, so is `g/d` (and vice versa). The only exception is in the case where `g` is a perfect square, in which case the square root of `g` appears as an "unpaired" divisor. Take a look at the list of divisors of *any* non-square integer, and you'll notice that there are always an even number of divisors (and always an odd number of divisors of a perfect square).

Comment: @MarkDickinson i gotta focus on the stock market. i'll brb hopefully within the hour

Comment: @MarkDickinson very interesting. by perfect square, you mean something like `3x3=9` or `4x4=16` whereby the "multipliers" are integers, right? so it's almost as if there's an "inflection" point at which point you've covered each half of every pair of factors. anyways, you should draft up your solution as an answer!

Answer (score 3):

This answer is more or less implementation of @MarkDickinson ideas in JS code. To re-iterate the main ideas are:

1. Ignore the two numbers problem. First find [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) and then factorize it.
2. When doing factorization it makes sense to find only prime divisors and calculate others
3. During the search for prime divisors it is enough to search up to the square root of the number. Moreover as new primes are found it makes sense to lower the square root estimate by removing (i.e. dividing by) known prime factors.

This code doesn't use any more sophisticated ideas such as [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). So here is the code:

```
const gcd = (a, b) => {
    const impl = (ai, bi) => ai ? impl(bi % ai, ai) : bi;
    // handle also case when a or b is 0 from the beginning
    return impl(Math.min(a, b), Math.max(a, b))
};

const factor = (v0) => {
    let v = v0;
    let factors = [1];

    const addFactors = (fs) => {
        if (fs.length > 0) {
            // pre-allocate space
            let newFactors = new Array(factors.length * fs.length);
            let o = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < factors.length; i++)
                newFactors[o++] = factors[i];

            for (let i = 0; i < factors.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < fs.length; j++) {
                    newFactors[o++] = factors[i] * fs[j];
                }
            }
            factors = newFactors;
        }
    };

    const addFactorPows = (f) => {
        // find all powers of the factor
        // Example; v = 12, f = 2
        // We want pows to be [2, 4]
        // This is important for addFactors to work correctly
        let p = 1;
        let pows = [];

        while (v % f === 0) {
            v /= f;
            p *= f;
            pows.push(p);
        }
        addFactors(pows);
        return (pows.length !== 0);
    };

    addFactorPows(2);

    let s = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(v));
    for (let i = 3; i <= s; i += 2) {
        if (addFactorPows(i)) {
            s = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(v));
        }
    }
    // probably add the last prime, unless there was a perfect square and v = 1
    if (v !== 1)
        addFactorPows(v);

    return factors.sort((a, b) => (a - b));
};

const commonFactors = (a, b) => {
    const g = gcd(a, b);
    return factor(g);
};
```

Probably the most complicated idea here is how `addFactorPows`/`addFactors` work. Essentially `factors` array holds the list of all factors of the `v0/v` i.e. factors of the multiplication of all the prime factors we've already found so far. The idea is that if we have some value `x` and all its `factors` and we want to know all factors of `p*x`, we just need to copy `factors` and also append to it a copy with each known factor multiplied by `p`. The only catch is that to avoid duplication if a prime factor `p` has multiplicity more than 1 we need to process `p`, `p^2`, ... at the same time instead of one by one.

Answer (score 2):

The following algorithm should return an array of all factors. It should be faster than just trying to divide all values because it uses prime factorization.

I did the following: [YouTube: Alle Teiler einer großen Zahl finden](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSq5f1iiQac) (The video is in german - just turn audio off - it's not necessary to understand the content). In words: My code calculates the prime factors of a given number and finally finds all missing factors by combining the prime factors (multiplication).

The algorithm will add more primes to the primes template array if the given primes are not enough. If you need to calculate the factors of a huge amount of numbers, this array can be reused. Nevertheless calculating new primes at runtime will slow down this algorithm. It would be better to add all primes of your possible numbers range to this array.

`console.log(findAllFactors(2252))` should return `[ 1, 2, 4, 563, 1126, 2252 ]`

**EDIT**: I have added one more function that compares the factors of two given numbers. It returns an array of their common factors.

**Calculating all factors of a given number**:

```
// The more primes you add to this array the lower is the 
// prohability for calculating new primes at runtime
// (minimum primes in array: [2, 3, 5])
const primes = [ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 ];


// Adds next prime to array "primes"
const addNextPrime = (lastPrime) => {
    const primeCandidate = lastPrime + (lastPrime % 10 === 3 ? 4 : 2);
    const sqrtNumber = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(primeCandidate));
    for(let i = 2; i < sqrtNumber + 1; i++) {
        if (primeCandidate % i === 0) {
            return addNextPrime(primeCandidate);
        }
    }
    primes.push(primeCandidate);
}

// returns array of prime factorization
const findPrimeFactors = (currentFactor, highestFactor = 0, primeFactors = []) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < primes.length; i++) {
        const mod = currentFactor % primes[i];
        if (highestFactor === 0 && mod === 0) {
            highestFactor = currentFactor / primes[i];
            primeFactors.push(primes[i]);
            return findPrimeFactors(currentFactor / primes[i], highestFactor, primeFactors);
        } else {
            if (primes[i] <= highestFactor) {
                if (i === primes.length - 1) {
                    addNextPrime(primes[primes.length - 1]);
                }
                if (mod === 0) {
                    primeFactors.push(primes[i]);
                    return findPrimeFactors(currentFactor / primes[i], highestFactor, primeFactors);
                }
            } else if (highestFactor) {
                return primeFactors;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Calculates the missing factors by combining prime factors
const findAllFactors = (input) => {
    const factors = findPrimeFactors(input);
    const primeCount = factors.length;
    let combinedFactor;
    for (let i = 0; i < primeCount - 1; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < primeCount; j++) {
            combinedFactor = (j === i + 1) ? factors[i] * factors[j] : combinedFactor * factors[j];
            factors.push(factors[i] * factors[j]);
            factors.push(combinedFactor);
        }
    }
    factors.push(1);
    return factors.sort((a, b) => a - b).filter((value, index, array) => index === array.indexOf(value));
}

console.log(findAllFactors(2252));
```

**Additionally: Calculating common factors of two given numbers**:

```
const commonFactors = (a, b) => {
    const aFactors = findAllFactors(a);
    const bFactors = findAllFactors(b);
    // still optimizable:
    return aFactors.filter(value => bFactors.includes(value));
}

console.log(commonFactors(24, 96));
```

Comment: i think i devised one that is incredibly more concise. i'll tag you in it. take a look and let me know what you think. if you see anything that can be improved, please do let me know! thanks for sharing your answer nonetheless <3

Comment: @Anthony yes, your code is more concise. But you asked for the most efficient way and not for the most concised code ;-) I think that my code could be faster in most cases. It could only slow down dramatically if you try to find the factors of a really high number that is the result of a really high prime square number which is not included in the primes array. By the way: I have edited my answer. It is now sorting and filtering the factor-array a provides a function to find common factors of two numbers.

Comment: the most efficient way in a coding context! hm... i haven't gotten a chance yet to understand it all thoroughly but i have my doubts that your code would perform faster. you should slap together a jsperf.com test and let's see

Answer (score 1):

you may use this code segment for calculating Common factors of two number.

```
var a = 98, b = 56, cf = 0;
while (b != 0)
 {
  cf = b;
  b = a % b;
  a = cf;
 }
console.log("CF: "+cf);
```

Comment: i'm sorry i don't see how that works or is even relevant. ['GCD' = greatest common denominator/factor/divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)

Comment: please do something about your answer or i will be forced to downvote it. sorry

Comment: @Anthony thanks for noticing it. I have updated the code segment. it will help to calculate the common factors of any two numbers.

Comment: thank you! i really like this since it's a lot easier to understand at a glance than `(a, z) => a ? gcd(z % a, a) : z`. it's actually really elegant!! however, i'm actually trying to find ALL of the common factors

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question plus is poorly written. Please remove this and make SO a better place!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out a concise and efficient way to do this.

I believe the `odd gdc` section can be improved by continually dividing `r` in "half". Are there any mathematicians or smart people out there who can verify this?

```js
const cf = (a,z) => {
  const gcd = (a, z) => a ? gcd(z % a, a) : z
  const g = gcd(a,z)
  const cfarr = g > 1 ? [1, g] : [1]
  let c
  console.log(g)
  if (g%2 > 0) {
    // odd gcd
    c = 3
    let r = Math.floor(g/2)
    r%2 === 0 ? r-=1 : r-=2
    while (c < g) {
      if (g%c === 0) cfarr.push(c)
      c+=2
    } 

  } else {
    // even gcd
    c = 2
    while (c < g/2) {
      let n = g/c
      if (c <= n && n%1 === 0) cfarr.push(c,n)
      c++
    }
  }
  console.log(cfarr+`
  `)
}


cf(9,27)
cf(333,2120)
cf(550,790)
cf(1850,2018)
```

Please let me know what you think and if you see any improvements or can improve it in any way!!

Comment: @MarkDickinson please let me know what you think!

Comment: Anthony, I'm not Mark but take a look at my answer with some of his ideas.

Comment: @SergGr i've looked at. really don't have the time to digest it all right now. the theory kind of falls in line with what i was told over at math exchange. is it more efficient than the code i wrote? or what exactly is wrong with my technique? it looks like a lot more code!

Comment: Efficiency should be measured and I didn't try it. Actually I think for efficiency it makes sense to inline my `addFactorPows`/`addFactor` which I moved to avoid duplication for `2` and other primes. The most important change IMHO comparing to your code is that in the my main loop go far less than `while (c < g)` or `while (c < g/2)`. They go at max to the square root and often much less. P.S. it should be noted that for your ranges of input value efficiency probably doesn't matter unless your are going to run the code hundreds or thousands of times

Comment: @SergGr but the thing is i need all of the factors, not just the factors that are smaller than the square root of the GCD. yeah, efficiency isn't a deal breaker but i prefer to do things the right/best way from the get go if you know what i mean

Comment: Anthony, If this is about my code - you can easily run it and see that it does generates all factors not just prime ones. As for general concern, one trick suggested by Mark Dickinson is that when you've found a factor `f`, you should calculate `g/f` and at it as well unless it is the same as `f` (in which case `g` = `f^2` and you've reached the finish). You use a less efficient kind of this trick for the "even" case and don't use at all for the "odd" case.

Comment: @SergGr yes, i was talking about your code. then what did you mean by your main loop goes less than square root? very true that i haven't implemented `g/f` yet for odd GCDs. how is my implementation for `even GCDs` less efficient?!?!?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161842/discussion-between-serggr-and-anthony).

Comment: @SergGr i gotta hit the hay here shortly. talk more tomo!

Comment: Anthony, I've put some details into the chat. Ask me there with @ if/when you have some questions regarding that.

Comment: @SergGr i forgot it's almost christmas lol. this is prolly gon have to wait :( i'll check it out as soon as possible though